# Lookup values from one JSON file and replace in another

Tags: json, translation, jq

I have 2 files
1. Translation.json

```
        {
       "sKEY": "CustomField.Account.Preferred_Name_Local_Language.Fieldlabel",
       "label": "Preferred Name",
       "translation": "Nombre Preferido",
        }
```

2. Form.json

```
        {
      "fullName": "Student_Information/Preferred_Name__pc",
      "description": "Preferred Name",
      "inlineHelpText": "Preferred Name",
      "label": "Preferred Name"          
        }
```

I need to lookup the "label" by value in translation.json and replace the "label" value in Form.json with the "tranlsation" value from translation.json.

Comment: Please take a look at the [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These two documents will help others answer your question quicker.

Comment: The translation.json as shown is a single object with a structure that seems unsuited for translation.  Does translation.json in reality consist of an array of such objects?  Or a stream?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as stated is a bit perplexing, but here is a solution, assuming that jq is invoked like so:

```
jq -f program.jq —-argfile dict translation.jq form.json
```

where program.jq contains:

```
.label |= if $dict.label == . then $dict.translation else . end
```

Equivalently:

```
if .label == $dict.label then .label = $dict.translation else . end
```

### if ... then ... end

The "master" version of jq allows `if ... then ... end` so that the above solutions can be respectively shortened to:

```
.label |= if $dict.label == . then $dict.translation end
```

and:

```
if .label == $dict.label then .label = $dict.translation end
```